# How to stretch a DIV horizontally to its content in a scrollable container?

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items inside a scrollable container. Each item has a `:hover` style applied. The problem is that if the container is scrolled, then the background gets cropped away, although content is fully visible.

How do I make the DIVs to stretch to full width of content, so it is highlighted entirely when hovering?

Here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2UISKfbzgzTdm6dNJG3V)

You can see that when you scroll horizontally to about halfway and then hover on items, only some part of them becomes red:

[image: cropped background]

```css
.box-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.item-container div:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px;">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="item-container">
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your plunkr code works fine for me, the whole line is highlighted.

Comment: Which browser you are using? @JustAMartin

Comment: I'm using Chrome 45.0.2454.101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds bit hacky, but works. `table` behaves in between inline and block level, the width is decided by the content and forces line break.

```
.item-container div {
   display: table;
}
```

```css
.box-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.item-container div {
    display: table;
}
.item-container div:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px;">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="item-container">
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
            <div>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I guess, `display: table` is an ugly child of CSS, but in some cases it is the simplest and most efficient solution.

Comment: Added more info. It is very powerful indeed, especially on some special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it 100vw on the div

```
.item-container div {
  width:100vw;

}
```

Comment: Then it becomes dependent on the width of the window and I get this http://i.imgur.com/kybdJBr.png or this http://i.imgur.com/pnkJaKo.png (depending on how wide I stretch the preview frame in Plunkr)